# Access Select Top 1 is not returning all rows

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have writing a select query to fetch the Top 1 record from a table ( one to many) which has multiple records for each ID. For example ID = 1, 2, and 3 .. each have multiple rows. The record has a Date field so I sort by that Date field and fetch the most recent record by that date. When I run my query, I am  missing records for ID 1 and 4. I checked the table and there are multiple records for those 2. I did a count distinct and it returns over 3000 and my query returns just 1400. The same IDs also exist in Table 1. Strange things is when I removed the Top 1, I see all the IDs. The query should take the first record for each ID, correct?

Here is my query

```
SELECT
table2.RecentDate,
table2.Name,
table2.Address,
table2.City,
table2.State

FROM [table1] 

INNER JOIN 
        (   SELECT  Top 1 *
            FROM    [table2]  
            ORDER BY [table2].RecentDate DESC

        ) table2
ON [table1].[ID] = table2.[ID]
```

Any Help is greatly appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: If you do an inner join, than it will only show results where the ID of both table 1 and table2 exists. So it might be the case that there are no records with those ID's in table2. also you only get the top 1 ordered by date, which doesn't take the ID into account at all..

Comment: Your inner query select **only 1 record**!!! `TOP 1` is not top 1 for each group, its TOP 1 from the entire data!

Comment: The IDs exist in both tables

Comment: why do you need `Table1`?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
table2.RecentDate,
table2.Name,
table2.Address,
table2.City,
table2.State

FROM [table2] 

INNER JOIN 
        (   SELECT  [ID], MAX(RecentDate) dt
            FROM    [table2]  
            GROUP BY [ID]    
        ) t2
ON [table2].[ID] = t2.[ID] and [table2].[RecentDate] = t2.[dt]
```

Comment: In case you didn't notice, all the records comes from table2, not table1 .

Comment: Thanks i didn't notice that @sagi  I changed it based on i don't see the use for Table1

Answer (score 0):

You can get the max row from table2 to do this. It should be more efficient than using TOP as well as returning what you are actually looking for.

```
SELECT
table2.RecentDate,
table2.Name,
table2.Address,
table2.City,
table2.State
FROM [table1] T1
INNER JOIN  [table2]  T2
ON T1.[ID] = T2.[ID]
AND T2.RECENT_DATE = (SELECT MAX(RECENT_DATE) FROM table2 T2E WHERE T2.ID=T2E.ID)
```

And if you don't need table1

```
select
table2.RecentDate,
table2.Name,
table2.Address,
table2.City,
table2.State
FROM [table2]  T2
WHERE T2.RECENT_DATE = (SELECT MAX(RECENT_DATE) FROM table2 T2E WHERE T2.ID=T2E.ID)
```